# Error in 'from torchtext.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator'

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am trying to implement this article https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-text-classification-using-pytorch-723dfb8b6b5b, but I have the following problem.

```
# Preliminaries
from torchtext.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator
```

Error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Field' from 'torchtext.data' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/data/__init__.py)


OSError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/_torchtext.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK3c104Type14isSubtypeOfExtESt10shared_ptrIS0_EPSo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator
```

Field is a legacy functionality of Torchtext since the 0.9 release. That article you linked was from before that release. If you've got the newest torchtext, but are trying to use legacy functionality, you need to use torchtext.legacy.*

Check out [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb) for more info.

Also [check this for full torchtext release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases).